# Array Set in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, set

I have code in scala :

```
 val graph = new Array [Set[Int]] (n)

 def addedge(i:Int,j:Int)
 {
     graph(i)+=j
 }
```

What does `graph(i)+=j` mean? 
Can anybody translate it in any other languages like c, c++ or java?

Answer (score 7):

`graph` is an `Array`, just like in C or Java.  `graph(i)` means "access the `ith` element of `graph`".  Each element in `graph` is a `Set` of `Int`s.  The `+=` method on `Set` adds an item to the `Set`.  So `graph(i) += j` adds the number `j` into the `Set` stored at index `i` in `graph`.

Trying things out in the REPL shows the behavior:

```
scala> val graph = Array(Set(1,2), Set(2,3), Set(1))
graph: Array[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]] = Array(Set(1, 2), Set(2, 3), Set(1))

scala> graph(1) += 4

scala> graph
res0: Array[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]] = Array(Set(1, 2), Set(2, 3, 4), Set(1))
```

Comment: how about this one ?'for(i<-0 until n)
  {
    graph(i)=Set[Int]();
    
  }'

Comment: @user194611, ask a new question as a new question